# Putting hyphen in every 3 digit of a string and 2 digits on the last group if possible

Tags: python

I need to create a program that allows string user input. And I have to only pick the numerical digits then group them by 3 digits each. Having 2 digits at the last group if the length of the string is not divisible by 3. Can anyone help me?

```
sample user input : ue3j8dj2pud7y3g378
Target output: 382-733-78

sample user input : babdh3uh23737gvrh27h3h4
Target output: 323-737-27-34

Sample user input: bs34bhev26gv362
Target output: 342-63-62
```

Comment: Hint: Regex replace.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem without regex:

```
my_string= 'ue3j8dj2pud7y3g378'

x = ''.join(c for c in my_string if c.isdigit())

y=""

myInt = len(x)- 5

rem = myInt % 3
quo = myInt/3

if rem == 0 and quo==1:


    y= '-'.join([x[:3], x[3:6], x[6:]])
    print y

elif rem == 2 and quo ==1:

    y ='-'.join([x[:3], x[3:6], x[6:8],x[8:]])
    print y
elif rem == 2 and quo == 0:
    y ='-'.join([x[:3], x[3:5], x[5:]])
    print y

else:

    print "--->"
```